# Can't deploy ASP.NET react Web App with individual accounts — fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, jwt, authorization, iis-7

I'm trying to deploy ASP.NET 7.0 web application with Individual accounts at IIS on Windows 11, using MSSQL DB on local PC, but have an error 500 and this lines at logs:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
```

I tried to run it on "Development" mode, then webapp has opened, but on registration and authorisation pages was white screen.
I tried to make clear standard web application by "dotnet new react -au Individual" but have this problem again (500 error on web browser and errors on log file). On visual studio all works (on Release, Debug, Deploy and Production modes), but after deploy on IIS — nothing worked.
I tried to change connection string on appsetyings.json to string of connection to my DB. It's working on my another ASP.NET 6.0 project, made in Visual studio, but there it's not working.
Here is full log file text:

```
info: Duende.IdentityServer.Startup[0]
      Starting Duende IdentityServer version 6.0.4+9dfb7e94e795f55b2c063d54d11b70aae05e4e07 (.NET 7.0.1)
warn: Duende[0]
      You do not have a valid license key for the Duende software. This is allowed for development and testing scenarios. If you are running in production you are required to have a licensed version. Please start a conversation with us: https://duendesoftware.com/contact
info: Duende.IdentityServer.Startup[0]
      Using explicitly configured authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Stable-Draw\Compiled App
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]
      Connection ID "18374686493361831941", Request ID "40000006-0003-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler'1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler'1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT'1.ProcessRequestAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]
      Connection ID "18302628890733969411", Request ID "40000004-0001-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler'1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler'1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT'1.ProcessRequestAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]
      Connection ID "18374686570671243267", Request ID "40000004-0015-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler'1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler'1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT'1.ProcessRequestAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]
      Connection ID "18158513706953080837", Request ID "40000006-0002-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler'1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT'1.ProcessRequestAsync()
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

Edit:
I tried migrating the database and add it to aspnetsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "DataSource=app.db;Cache=Shared"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Store",
      "StoreName": "WebHosting",
      "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
      "Name": "CN=stabledraw.com"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

But that only partially solved the problem, and I get another error: `HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start`
And this string at the log file:
`Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't find a valid certificate with subject 'CN=stabledraw.com' on the 'CurrentUser\WebHosting'`
I have purchased certificates, but I can't understand what kind of certificate (or key) is needed, in what format, where should I put it and how to set the path to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by add next appsettings.Production.json file:

```
{
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "..\\stabledraw.com.pfx",
      "Password": "pass_of_pfx"
    }
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://stabledraw.com"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://stabledraw.com",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "server.pfx",
          "Password": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you generate the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#deploy-to-production), you could find:

To deploy the app to production, the following resources need to be provisioned:

A database to store the Identity user accounts and the IdentityServer grants.

A production certificate to use for signing tokens. There are no specific requirements for this certificate; it can be a self-signed certificate or a certificate provisioned through a CA authority. It can be generated through standard tools like PowerShell or OpenSSL. It can be installed into the certificate store on the target machines or deployed as a .pfx file with a strong password.

So you need to add these settings into your application's appsettings.json

For example:

```
"IdentityServer": {
  "Key": {
    "Type": "Store",
    "StoreName": "WebHosting",
    "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
    "Name": "CN=MyApplication"
  }
}
```

Besides, Duende Software might require you to pay a license fee for production use of Duende Identity Server.

Comment: Thanks, It works, but now I get next problem with it. I wrote it as "Edit" of my question. Would really appreciate any help becouse I'm new in ASP.NET

Comment: You need to install the certficate inside the certificate manager inside the your serveräs CurrentUser\WebHosting path.