# NET7 application doesn't work with Individual Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, duende-identity-server

I'm creating a web application with *ASP.NET Core* (NET7) with *Individual Authentication* based on *Identity Server*. The application is hosted on a web provider and on its servers NET7 is installed.

When I run the application, I get a lot of errors

```html
info: Duende.IdentityServer.Startup[0]
      Starting Duende IdentityServer version 6.0.4+9dfb7e94e795f55b2c063d54d11b70aae05e4e07 (.NET 7.0.10)
warn: Duende[0]
      You do not have a valid license key for the Duende software. This is allowed for development and testing scenarios. If you are running in production you are required to have a licensed version. Please start a conversation with us: https://duendesoftware.com/contact
info: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ConfigureApiResources[2]
      Configuring local API resource 'LIU.Website.ServerAPI'.
info: Duende.IdentityServer.Startup[0]
      Using explicitly configured authentication scheme Identity.Application for IdentityServer
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {daa782a9-098f-46fe-afad-f2755e42ffa2} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: E:\Vhosts\forum.com\httpdocs\languageinuse
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes/DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 47
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 27
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes/DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 47
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 27
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatcher|8_0(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task`1 matcherTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[3]
      An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes/DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 47
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 27
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[3]
      An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes/DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 47
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 27
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatcher|8_0(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task`1 matcherTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]
      Connection ID "7998392960490152553", Request ID "4000226a-0005-6f00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.DynamicProviders.DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/DynamicProviders/DynamicSchemes/DynamicSchemeAuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 47
         at Duende.IdentityServer.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Hosting/BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 27
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|8_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]
      Connection ID "15852688307105306980", Request ID "40001965-1006-dc00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IdentityServerJwtBearerOptionsConfiguration.ResolveAuthorityAndKeysAsync(MessageReceivedContext messageReceivedContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.
```

I read on this [post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136779/how-to-create-a-signing-certificate-and-use-it-in-identityserver4-in-production) that I can create my own self-signed certificate and use it in the Identity Server. Followed the instruction with PowerShell:

```
New-SelfsignedCertificate 
  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable 
  -Subject "CN=MyIdsvCertificate" 
  -KeySpec Signature 
  -KeyAlgorithm RSA 
  -KeyLength 2048 
  -HashAlgorithm SHA256 
  -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

Because I can't install the certificate on the server, I exported the certificate I created (as a `.pfx`) in the application folder and checked the property to "Copy always" the certificate.

[image]

then, following this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971494/cant-deploy-asp-net-react-web-app-with-individual-accounts-fail-microsoft-as), I added in the *appconfig.json* the reference to the certificate like that

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
        "LIU.Website.Client": {
            "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
        }
    },
    "Key": {
        "Type": "File",
        "FilePath": ".\\liu.pfx",
        "Password": "mypassword"
    }
}
```

When I run the application, I get this error

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: �. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

[image]

What is the correct process? How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [post](https://damienbod.com/2020/02/10/create-certificates-for-identityserver4-signing-using-net-core/) that has a [GitHub](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreCertificates) repo. With the code in the repo, I managed to create a certificate for the Identity Server and added it in the *Program.cs* with this code

```
var pth = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
pth = Path.Combine(pth, "cert_rsa512.pfx");

var rsaCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pth, "Enrico!1975*", 
    X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddSigningCredential(rsaCertificate)
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
        options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
    });
```

The flags are important because the server will search the certificate on the local machine. With this flags, it searches the certificate in the file system or in the local machine.